# Drupal - expose filters in a views feed

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, view

I have a repository project
it records all data about products that come in or out of this repository

for example

product name ------ number  ------ in / out  ------ where

Procuts A ----------- 125 ------------- in -------------    null

Procuts B ------------ 85 ------------- in -------------    null

Procuts C ----------- 100 ------------- in -------------    null

Procuts D ----------- 525 ------------- in -------------    null

Procuts A ----------- 110 ------------- Out ---------- company 1

Procuts B ----------- 105 ------------- Out ---------- company 2

Procuts C ----------- 305 ------------- Out ---------- company 3

Procuts D ----------- 255 ------------- Out ---------- company 4

Procuts E ----------- 195 ------------- Out ---------- company 1

with **views** module, i made a table with datas like this and with **expose filter** to all fields in the table in order to change result

but i want to change results with exposed filter and export it in **EXCEL** file

Answer (score 0):

Here is the module which is frequently used by developers to export views data.[View's data export](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_data_export)
There is a issue regarding the export data with expose filter, but it was resolve Patch is available [here](https://www.drupal.org/node/1322816)
You can export data into CSV file.